# get user that reacted first discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

the part of my code

```
   const emodjimessage = await message.channel.send(duelrequest)
   
        emodjimessage.react("⛔")

 emodjimessage.awaitReactions({max: 1, time: 90000, errors: ["time"]}).then(collected => {
      
        const reaction = collected.first();


      switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
        case "⛔":

        // some code here
           

        break
}
})
```

Hello! i want to get id of the user who reacted to the message first, but i have no idea, how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `awaitReactions()` method will return a collection of reaction objects, so you can do `collected.first()` to get the first one, as you have done.

From here, you can get the user and their ID like so

```js
let firstReaction = collection.first();
let firstUser = firstReaction.user;
let firstUserId = firstUser.id;
```

Comment: So, you would want to loop through all the reactions and get the ID of each one?

Comment: no, i need id of user who reacted first only

Comment: In that case, the code above should work fine.